# Google Analytics: What does "?__c=1" refer to?

Tags: google-analytics

I usually notice `?__c=1` in my `Google Analytics` Traffic Reports/Realtime, and I don't know what it refers to. I already searched for it, but I couldn't find any information!

Here's a snapshot:

[image: What does ?__c=1 mean in Google Analytics]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google Analytics. GA simply collects and displays data based on your implemented measurement. So you could either investigate where this specific traffic comes from, or you should investigate your measurement settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/